# how to bring application to front with xdg-open

Tags: linux, ubuntu

On linux, xdg-open can launch an application, but in most cases the desired behavior is to only launch the application if it's not already running, and to bring it to the front if it is already running.

Can xdg-open do this? Is there some other standard way to provide this functionality?

Comment: Well you should ask this question on [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com), you can find better answers there. Because Stack Overflow is for programming related question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see `xdg-open` is nothing more then the wrapper which handles the file type and opens it in the preferred application. It's up to the application if it does or doesn't support **"bring to front"** option.

```
$ file /usr/bin/xdg-open
/usr/bin/xdg-open: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

In order to bring to front the application window you might use other tools like `wmctrl`, `xdotool` or `qdbus`.

Details:

```
NAME
       wmctrl - interact with a EWMH/NetWM compatible X Window Manager.

SYNOPSIS
       wmctrl [ options | actions ]...

DESCRIPTION
       wmctrl  is a command that can be used to interact with an X Window man‐
       ager that is compatible with the EWMH/NetWM specification.  wmctrl  can
       query  the window manager for information, and it can request that cer‐
       tain window management actions be taken.
[...]
       -a <WIN>
              Switch to the desktop containing the  window  <WIN>,  raise  the
              window, and give it focus.



NAME
       xdotool - command-line X11 automation tool

SYNOPSIS
       xdotool cmd args...

       Notation: Some documentation uses [window] to denote an optional window
       argument. This case means that the argument, if not present, will
       default to "%1". See "WINDOW STACK" for what "%1" means.

DESCRIPTION
       xdotool lets you programatically (or manually) simulate keyboard input
       and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc. It does this using
       X11's XTEST extension and other Xlib functions.

       There is some support for Extended Window Manager Hints (aka EWMH or
       NetWM).  See the "EXTENDED WINDOW MANAGER HINTS" section for more
       information.
```

Comment: Bring the window to the front with `wmctrl -a <WIN>`, where `<WIN>` is the title of the window. List all your managed windows with `wmctrl -l`, and the title appears as the last column.